# JPA Hibernate PostgreSQL current_date doesn't work

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, playframework, jpa-2.0

I have a PostgreSQL 9.3.6 database with the following query defined:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW calls_today AS
SELECT
    cc.*
FROM
    call_config cc
WHERE
    cc.created_at >= current_date;
```

The view is used on the web portal developed with Play Framework + Hibernate via JPA 2. Everything seems to work fine except the date related queries.

If the server is restarted today, the view looks like working but only today. Tomorrow, I will see on the web page all the calls from the last two days. The next day, another one more, so three days and so on.
If I issue the query on the psql client, the results are fine, just the current day.

I must be missing something, it doesn't look like the query results were cached (as each day the result grows) but rather *current_date* was fixed at the day of the server restart. Like some kind of prepared statement, I really don't know.

The data is pulled from the database with the following JPA 2 API:

```
private static<T extends IOutgoingCallConfig> Result getCalls(Class<T> entityClass) {
Check.Argument.isNotNull(entityClass, "entityClass");

List<CallItem> calls = new ArrayList<>();

EntityManager em = JPA.em();

CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<T> cq = cb.createQuery(entityClass);
Root<T> rootEntry = cq.from(entityClass);
CriteriaQuery<T> all = cq.select(rootEntry);
TypedQuery<T> allQuery = em.createQuery(all);

for(T entity: allQuery.getResultList()) {
   calls.add(new CallItem(entity));
}

    return jsonSuccess(calls);
}
```

I have tested via psql that the following prepared query:

```
prepare mystmt as select current_time;
```

doesn't suffer this problem. Each execution reveals the updated current server time:

```
execute mystmt;
```

Having a simple view like below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_current_time as select current_time;
```

causes the same problems. One the query has been run, the return value is always the same :(

It might be related to the definition of the current_time and current_date.
From [PostgreSQL 9.4 documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT):

> Since these functions return the start time of the current transaction, their values do not change during the transaction. This is considered a feature: the intent is to allow a single transaction to have a consistent notion of the "current" time, so that multiple modifications within the same transaction bear the same time stamp.

Comment: First, please answer the question - does query (TABLE calls_today) output changes from day to day ? If yes, it is hibernate/JPA problem, if not - postgres.

Comment: Just tested your my_current_time view on my postgresql 9.4 install. When querying the view from pgAdmin the value in the view updates as expected. So it seems to be a problem on the hibernate side. Probably caching so try to switch that of. You probably can also log all queries then you could see if it actually queries the view.

Comment: Yes, the view runs fine. Only todays calls are returned.

Comment: For some reason, the transaction scope spans future requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be transaction scope problem.
My controller is annotated with:

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
```

as it only reads the data. For some reason, the transaction scope spans all future requests :( I'm a little bit surprised here. I would expect either having a transaction for each request or not having at all (auto commit transaction).

I have changed

```
current_date
```

with

```
date_trunc('day', clock_timestamp())
```

and now it runs fine even via Hibernate.

I guess I must read more about Hibernate and JPA 2 or I could run into similar problems if I don't understand the transaction scope clearly.